# Remove html from text but keep <br> tags in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using python to obtain data from a website and I need to remove all the html and \n\t but keeping all the text and "br" tags

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-text-inner"]').extract()
```

Output

```
['<div class="comment-text-inner">\n\t\t\t\t<b>Certified, Low Mileage, Twin Panel Moonroof, SE Convenience Package, Rear Parking  Aid Sensors, Black Roof Side Rails, Sync 3, Power 10-Way 
Driver Seat, SE Leather Plus Package, Voice-Activated Touch-Screen <br>
Navigation!</b><br> <br>    
Whether you\'re getting out of the city for a weekend camping trip or just driving to the grocery store, the 2017 
Ford Escape has you covered. This  2017 Ford Escape is for sale today. <br> <br>
For 2017, the Escape has under gone a small refresh, updating the exterior with a more angular tailgate, LED tail lights, an aluminum hood and a new fascia that makes it look similar to the other Ford crossovers.  
Both programs offer you an exclusive Comprehensive Warranty over and above any remaining factory warranty. For specific details on either program see your sales representative today!<br> <br><br>AMVIC Licensed Dealer<br> Come by and check out our fleet of 40+ used cars and trucks and 70+ new cars and trucks for sale in Calgary.  o~o\t\t\t</div>']
```

Using  `response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-text-inner"]/text()').extract()` 
 returns text with \n\t and without the "br" tags so I need to remove the \n\t and keep the br tags

Comment: What's 'response'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "what's response" ? Are you familiar with scrapy?
I'm putting the result it in a variable to be added to a database afterwards.

Comment: What webpage do you scrape to get this HTML?

Comment: So, you want to remove `<b>` tags, the wrapping `<div>` tag, but keep `<br>`? Would it be OK to replace the `<br>` with the corresponding line breaks? See [html-text](https://pypi.org/project/html-text/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code that does what you want:

```
children = response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-text-inner"]/node()')  
res = ""
for c in children:   
   name = c.xpath("name()") 
   if len(name) == 0 or c.get() == "<br>": 
     text = c.get() 
     text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "") 
     res = res + text
     print(text)  # not strictly needed
```

Here, I'm printing the text - but you can of course put it in a database or do something else instead.

(The URL I used is https://www.marlboroughford.com/vehicle-details/used-2017-ford-escape-se---certified---low-mileage-calgary-ab-id-36312139)

Comment: I need to remove all the html and just keep the br tags with the text.

Comment: "all the HTML" - you mean remove all tags other than <br> ?

Comment: Yes. All the tags other than <br>

Answer (score 0):

1.save html 
2.in html replace `<br>`tag by something that 100% will not appear on text and will not recognized as tag for `../text()` Xpath selector or `::text` for css selector (as it happened on your previous attempt to use `text` selector). for example by `__br__` 
3.call `text` selector on modified html code. 
4.in received text - replace back `__br__` by `<br>`

```
from scrapy import Selector
...
...
..
def parse(self, response):
    ....
    html = response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-text-inner"]').extract()
    # replace '<br>` by __br__ 
    html = html.replace("<br>", "__br__")
    # create selector from modified html code
    sel = Selector(text=html)
    text = sel.css("*::text").extract()
    
    #convert list to string:
    if text:
        text = ",".join(text)
        # you can use `strip` for removing \t and \n
        # text = "".join([t.strip("\t\n") for t in text if t.strip("\t\n")])
    # or use replace
    # text = text.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")

   # return <br> tags back to result:
   text = text.replace("__br__", "<br>")
```

Comment: I was getting an error on line "html = html.replace("<br>", "__br__")" but I was able to fix it using "html = [x.replace("<br>", "__br__") for x in html]" and that replaces <br> for _br_
The problem now is line "sel = Selector(text=html)" is giving an error "TypeError: to_bytes must receive a str or bytes object, got list"

Comment: In case if your target page has only one `div class comment text inner` tag you can use: `response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-text-inner"]').extract_first("")` instead of `....-inner"]').extract()` without change `"__br__"` to `"br", This changes should solve `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to remove all tags. but prior it you have to replace 
 tag to something else, to keep it the text

```
text = response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-text-inner"]').extract()
text = ' '.join(text) if text else ''
text = re.sub(r'<br>', '__br__', text) #replace <br> to return it in text
text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text) # remove all tags
text = text.replace('__br__', '<br>').strip() # return <br> tag back into text
```

Comment: The second line of code is giving an error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".

Comment: yeah, need to convert list to a string, updated code above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with scrapy, but given the html, you can subclass the standard library's [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser) to process it.

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class TagStripper(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._content = []
        self.trans_table = str.maketrans('', '', '\n\t')

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'br':
            self._content.append('<br>')

    def handle_data(self, data):
        text = data.translate(self.trans_table)
        self._content.append(text)

    def get_result(self):
        return ''.join(self._content)


parser = TagStripper()
parser.feed(html_string)
print(parser.get_result())
```